# Why does cElementTree iterparse return None elements?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse an xml file with cElementTree.iterparse.
However, I can't understand what is going on because iterparse returns empty elements. 
I have an xml file that has the following approximate layout:

```
<DOCS>
  <ID id="1">
    <HEAD>title1</HEAD>
    <DATE>21.01.2010</DATE>
    <TEXT>
      <P>some text</P>
      <P>some text</P>
      <P>some text</P>
    </TEXT>
  </ID>

  <ID id="2">
    <HEAD>title2</HEAD>
    <DATE>21.01.2010</DATE>
    <TEXT>
      some text
    </TEXT>
  </ID>
</DATA>
```

I am trying to extract text from `TEXT` tag or iterate through `TEXT` tag children (`P` tags) and extract text from them as well.

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as cet

docs = {}
id = ''
for event, elem in cet.iterparse(xml_data, events=('end',)):
    if elem.tag == 'ID':
        id = elem.attrib['id']
    if elem.tag == 'TEXT':
        if list(elem):
            docs[id] = ''.join([p.text for p in elem])
        else:
            docs[id] = elem.text
#print(docs)
return docs
```

When I execute my code I get:

```
    docs[id] = ''.join([p.text for p in elem])
TypeError: sequence item 14: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Which means that one of `p` in a list comprehension `[p.text for p in elem]` is `None`. Ok, I used print statements to know which was the previous `p` text to see if there is something wrong with xml file tags. Well, the `p` element which does not have any text in fact should have it because it has a text body in the xml file. Can somebody explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake of forgetting the `if event == 'end':` check.

So, what is going on is that only when the `event == 'end'` we have a fully populated `elem` object.